# perform a calculation once in Button Action in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button in which there i'm doing some multiply and divisions and pass that value to another VC. whenever the button is pressed the calculation happens again and it increment the values again n again. I want that the calculation should be done once whenever the button action is performed.I'm passing value through NSUserdefault in another VC. My code is this,

```
 paymentTotal = (grandTotal /100) * 2.5 + 0.20;
                    grandTotal = grandTotal + paymentTotal;
                   self.lblGrandTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%.2f", grandTotal];
                    NSLog(@"Total: %@",self.lblGrandTotal.text);
                    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    // saving an NSString
                    [prefs setObject:self.lblGrandTotal.text forKey:@"GrandTotal"];
                    NSLog(@"Save_Order_Data: %@", self.save_order_data);
                    CardExampleViewController *exampleVC = [CardExampleViewController new];
                    exampleVC.delegate = self;
                    exampleVC.save_order_data = self.save_order_data;
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:exampleVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
  if(paymentTotal != 0)
  {
      paymentTotal = (grandTotal /100) * 2.5 + 0.20;
      grandTotal = grandTotal + paymentTotal;
  }
```

Comment: than how can i pass the grandtotal value to another VC? @Sh_Khan

Comment: you already use defaults , you also can declare a variable in destination VC and assign it before push

Comment: will it again increment the amount if i press the button again? @Sh_Khan

Comment: it is globally defined. @Sh_Khan